# How to extract the p value about if there is a statistically-significant diiference between the medians using the survfit function?

Tags: r, median, survival-analysis, p-value

I applied survival analysis on the example df

```
library(survival)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  time = rexp(500, rate = 0.02),  # Exponential survival times
  status = sample(0:1, 500, replace = TRUE),  # Event status (0=censored, 1=event)
  arm = sample(1:2, 500, replace = TRUE)  # Treatment arm
)

# Fit the survival model using Kaplan-Meier estimator

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ arm, data = data)
fit
```

the output of fit is as follows

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ arm, data = data)

        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
arm=1 262    132   66.5    56.9    78.7
arm=2 238    119   73.9    63.7    86.5
```

Is there a significant difference between the two medians? How to obtain the p value for that? Is it enough to do the logrank test to know the answer or am I missing something?

Comment: What p-value do you mean? The p-value is the result of an hypothesis being tested, what conclusion are you trying to draw from the results?

Comment: I have just updated the example. please check it out

Comment: are you specifically interested in testing the median values or the entire survival distribution? This question might be better suited for stat exchange which is a site for statistical questions

Comment: I am interested in finding a code in R to extract a p value regarding if there is a statistically significant difference between the 2 medians or not

Comment: This type of analysis is usually done using either a Cox proportional hazards model (`coxph()`on R), or an accelerated failure time model (`survreg()`) to evaluate the relevance of `arm` on the event _risk_. Comparing medians alone is usually insufficient, as you are only looking at a single point in time. E.g. you may have two wildly different survival curves that cross near the median survival time. Looking at those medians alone you may conclude that the arms aren't different, even if their curves (i.e. their risk of event) are.